# Can't see any files inside /mnt/d in linux ubuntu 18.04 LTS terminal in my Windows using WSL 2

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I was new on WSL, I know how to change directory from `C:` to `D:` in Linux Ubuntu 18.04, when I change the directory from `C:` to `D`: (which is in `/mnt/d`) I can't see any of files that already exist in `D:` by using `dir` or `ls` command, and when I try to create a new folder it was the only one that appears in Linux terminal but it doesn't appear in windows CMD by using `dir` command nor in windows file explorer even though I refresh, re-open, or toggling view hidden file checkbox in windows file explorer. So how can I resolve this problem? I'm using Windows 10 x64 system and WSL 2.

Edited

there is no file `/etc/wsl.conf` in my system.
Here is the output when I using the command `mount`

```
/dev/sdd on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /mnt/wsl type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
D:\ on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-18.04/f37594baee6ec4801fddf040d32f12cf5cbafe9e686121ddf5b37fb3b44445ca type 9p (rw,noatime,dirsync,aname=drvfs;path=D:\;uid=1000;gid=1000;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=65536,trans=fd,rfd=8,wfd=8)
none on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/shared-sockets/guest-services type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
none on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/shared-sockets/host-services type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
/dev/sdb on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache/6642e64e24d36fc55392d69dfa17d4927c69176946abdce3108b63b125b4a69a.iso on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools type iso9660 (ro,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)
tmpfs on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/tarcache/entries/docker.tar/d7013e1645611ae679e4be13d2f5f5e374677d70b93f325417998764598dbb7c/containers/services/docker/tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/tarcache/entries/docker.tar/d7013e1645611ae679e4be13d2f5f5e374677d70b93f325417998764598dbb7c/containers/services/docker/tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/tarcache/entries/docker.tar/d7013e1645611ae679e4be13d2f5f5e374677d70b93f325417998764598dbb7c/containers/services/docker/tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
overlay on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/tarcache/entries/docker.tar/d7013e1645611ae679e4be13d2f5f5e374677d70b93f325417998764598dbb7c/containers/services/docker/rootfs type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/containers/services/docker/lower,upperdir=/containers/services/docker/tmp/upper,workdir=/containers/services/docker/tmp/work)
overlay on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/tarcache/entries/docker.tar/d7013e1645611ae679e4be13d2f5f5e374677d70b93f325417998764598dbb7c/containers/services/docker/rootfs type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/containers/services/docker/lower,upperdir=/containers/services/docker/tmp/upper,workdir=/containers/services/docker/tmp/work)
overlay on /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/tarcache/entries/docker.tar/d7013e1645611ae679e4be13d2f5f5e374677d70b93f325417998764598dbb7c/containers/services/docker/rootfs type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/containers/services/docker/lower,upperdir=/containers/services/docker/tmp/upper,workdir=/containers/services/docker/tmp/work)
tools on /init type 9p (ro,relatime,dirsync,aname=tools;fmask=022,loose,access=client,trans=fd,rfd=6,wfd=6)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3177716k,nr_inodes=794429,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
none on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
C:\ on /mnt/c type 9p (rw,noatime,dirsync,aname=drvfs;path=C:\;uid=1000;gid=1000;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=65536,trans=fd,rfd=8,wfd=8)
```

Comment: Is D: mounted within WSL? Check with `mount`.

Comment: I agree with @DuncG on running a `mount` command and edit your question to provide that output.  Also, do you have a `/etc/wsl.conf`?  If WSL has created a '/mnt/d', it seems that at some point it tried to auto-mount it.  Either it is only half-completing the process (creating the mount point, but failing on the mount), or at some point in the past it created `/mnt/d`, but now something (perhaps `/etc/wsl.conf`) is telling it to not automount any longer.  Or something else ;-), but those are the two paths I'd look at for now.